# How to add space to apache tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, out-of-memory

I have a Hibernate/JPA + Primefaces/JSF application running on Tomcat **7.0** 
and my server gets an upgrade from **8Go** to **16Go** and I want to increase the space allocation to my application my question is

1. How to do it?
2. Adding more space to my application will make it faster (user experience)?

(I am working with Apache Tomcat **7.0** ) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of things you can configure to increase performance. Not only does Tomcat itself offer different settings, but the obvious JVM settings to tune performance can also be done. For a more in-depth analysis on increasing Tomcat performance, you can refer to,

https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-performance.

For some general JVM tips, please refer to,

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/integrator.311/integrator_install/src/cli_ldi_server_config.html

The connectors defined in Tomcat can also be tweaked to tune performance, as described here,

[Tomcat performance tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707508/tomcat-performance-tuning)

And yes, most of these changes will increase memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will check and try it and will give you feedback.